# No output from class using instance method on a code editor

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the instance method for some testing purposes.

The code does not return an output when I check on an IDE, example vscode or anything else:

```
class cal:
    def add(inst,a,b):
        return a+b
    def sub(inst,a,b):
        return a-b

c=cal()
c.add(5,3)
c.sub(5,3)
```

But it does return an output when we check it using command line Python interpreter:

```
>>> class cal:
...     def add(inst,a,b):
...             return a+b
...     def sub(inst,a,b):
...             return a-b
...
>>> c=cal()
>>> c.add(5,3)
8
>>> c.sub(5,3)
2
```

What am I missing when checking through IDE?

Comment: That dupe isn't very good. The reason it's printing in the second case and not the first is that in the second case, you're running in a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). It automatically prints the result of the evaluated expressions. If you're not running in a REPL, you need to manually `print` out things you want to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do print(c.add(5,3))